# How can I count the depth of a child element from a parent using xpath?

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium

Using Selenium, I can find the child and the parent elements. How do I could the depth of a child from a specified parent?

Here's a small sample of HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And here is the xpath that I use to find the parent of the img tag.

```
document.evaluate('../ancestor::div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " header ")]', $('img')[0], null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
```

So I now what to count the number of elements between the parent and the child using xpath. I'm aware of the count method in xpath, however I'm inexperienced on how this can still be done. The result should be that the  parent is 5 levels away from the  tag.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible in xpath straight away. I guess you will have to write a js function for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would second @benjamind's answer that it's probably a little diffcult to do this in XPath directly. But we may use a little trick: the depth that you are looking for can be computed as the difference between the depth of the `img` tag to the root tag and the depth of the parent tag to the root tag. Try this:

```
count(ancestor::*) - count(ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' header ')][1]/ancestor::*)
```

Comment: I came to this conclusion too so this will work for now. I know I could always figure this out using JavaScript and jQuery, but I want an XPath solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen to do it in javascript with jQuery, the following functions should do the work:

```
       function getDistanceFromElement(src){
            return getDistance(src, 10, 1);
        }

        function getDistance(src, maxDepth, distance){
            if(maxDepth > 0) {
                var parent = $(src).parent();
                if($(parent).hasClass("header")) {
                    return distance + 1;
                } else {
                    return getDistance(parent, maxDepth - 1, distance + 1);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
```

With the following HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img id="my_image"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

, the following call will display 5:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var srcImage = $("#my_image");

    var d = getDistanceFromElement(srcImage);
    alert(d);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simpler than benjamin.d's approach
`$("#my_image").parentsUntil("div[class='header']").length + 1;`

Note that `+ 1` is used to count `<div class="header">` as well. Without it this function returns the number of elements that lies *between* the inspected ones.